# Mocking a Kafka consumer in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, mocking

I'm trying to mock a [Kafka Consumer](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) in `Scala`. However, I'm getting a `NullPointerException`.

The following is my mocking code:

```scala
val kafkaConsumerMock: KafkaConsumer[String, Any] = mock[KafkaConsumer[String, Any]]
```

The error I'm getting is:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:501)
    at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.addDeserializerToConfig(ConsumerConfig.java:523)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:629)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:610)
```

When I'm trying to debug, I see that there are multiple constructors, each calling a private constructor at the end. Thereafter the private constructor performs some checks, and throws an NPE as the configs I'm passing to KafkaConsumer are `null` (but mocking shouldn't require parameters to be passed, right?).

What I'm unable to understand is, why is the actual code being called when I'm trying to mock? Also, how do I get around this?

Edit: I'm using `MockFactory`

Attached herewith is the debug status. `mock` returns a `null` consumer.

[image: This is the debug point status]

Comment: We'd need the whole code to help you but pretty sure there is some code that is not using the mock you created.

Comment: Also which mock library are you using?

Comment: @GaëlJ, I created a breakpoint at the time I initialize the mockConsumer. That itself is the point of failure. The test hasn't even begun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize a [`MockConsumer`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/MockConsumer.html) rather than using external mocking library.

Or if you want to inject mocks into another class, your external class would need to use the [`org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer.html) interface rather than `KafkaConsumer` implementation.

Comment: I had tried to use `MockConsumer`, but got an error: `type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.MockConsumer[String, Any]
 required: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer[String,Any]
      kafkaConsumerMock,`
How do I cast a MockConsumer to a KafkaConsumer?

Comment: You should change your variable types wherever you are assigning that (wherever you inject the mock) to just be Kafka Consumer interface https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer.html

Answer (score 1):

your problem is *trying to mock some class* that is not *Abstract*. You can `mock` some *traits* or Java *interfaces* or *abstract classes* but not *regular classes*. So, as @OneCricketeer advised, you can use `MockConsumer` which should be assigned to a value of `Consumer[String, Any]` type:

```scala
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{Consumer, MockConsumer, OffsetResetStrategy}
val kafkaConsumerMock: Consumer[String, Any] = new MockConsumer[String, Any](OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST)
```

or mock `Consumer[String, Any]`

```scala
val kafkaConsumerMock: Consumer[String, Any] = mock[Consumer[String, Any]]
```